# Copy data from one column to another in the same tab

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

I need a macro to copy data from one column to another that's located in the same tab.
So let's say that i have data in column F, from F3:F11 and I need to copy it to G3:G11

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Cells F3:F11 have formulas which are used to pull data from another worksheet, so if i just copy that data to G3:G11 it will also copy formulas which i don't want to do. That's why i wanted to use a macro so i don't have to enter data manually everyday.

And also I can't use any formulas for other reasons.

Answer (score 1):

This might not require a macro (Google Script) depending on your usage. You can achieve this with a simple formula:

In cell `G3`, simply put `=ARRAYFORMULA(F3:F11)` and the data will copy in real time.

If for some reason a formula cannot achieve your purpose, please edit your question to clarify.